# AWS CLI: disable distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

As far as I have understood, *disabling a cloudfront distribution* means *updating it's status* and is necessary to be able to delete it.

Given the very sparse documentation of the AWS CLI, I am looking for a minimal example of how to do that update using just the CLI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I can't provide you a minimal example, the following should work.  You can obtain jq from your distribution's repository or from http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/.

1. Get the Etag, will need it for step 3:

   $ **aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id E123456 | jq '. | .ETag'**

Get current config:

2. $ **aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id E123456 | jq '. | .DistributionConfig' > /tmp/disable-distribution-E123456**

   Modify /tmp/disable-distribution-E123456, distribution config file to disable.

   Relevant section:

   ```
   "DefaultRootObject": null,
   "PriceClass": "PriceClass_All",
   "Enabled": true,  <-- Set to false
   ```

Update Distribution:

3. $ **aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E123456 --if-match E3SVA578MZF6JZ --distribution-config file:///tmp/disable-distribution-E123456**

Comment: I see, this makes perfect sense. Now the disabling of a distribution takes some time, and it seems as if deleting can only occur, when the update has finished. So is there a way to delete a distribution in *one* script (kind of "scheduling" the deletion) or do I have to put it into two scripts that run with a delay of half an hour?

Comment: The only way I know is the latter.

Answer (score 7):

Oddly enough, the proposed solutions did not work for me. I kept getting

```
An error occurred (DistributionNotDisabled) when calling the DeleteDistribution operation: The distribution you are trying to delete has not been disabled.
```

when calling `aws cloudfront delete-distribution`.

The issue seems to be that you can't immediately disable the distribution with `aws cloudfront update-distribution`, its status taking a while to be updated (cf. the AWS Console, where the status is shown as 'In Progress').

In summary, the following sequence of commands solved my issue:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution
aws cloudfront wait distribution-deployed
aws cloudfront delete-distribution
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is entire script for disabling distribution automatically:

```
    id=E234343434

    tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/script.XXXXXX)
    tmpfile2=$(mktemp /tmp/script.XXXXXX)
    aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id $id | \
       jq .DistributionConfig.Enabled=false > $tmpfile
    jq -r .DistributionConfig $tmpfile > $tmpfile2
    aws cloudfront update-distribution --id $id \
        --if-match $(jq .ETag $tmpfile -r) \
        --distribution-config file://$tmpfile2
    rm $tmpfile $tmpfile2
```

and to delete:

```
aws cloudfront delete-distribution --id $id --if-match \
  $(aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id $id | jq .ETag -r)
```

Answer (score 1):

A full example of undeploying an deleting a distribution. Script waits until distribution is disabled and then delets it. This is working with aws-cli/2.0.49.

```
 echo "Gettiuing cloudfront info"
    DISTRIBUTION_ID=$(cat ars/cloudfront-@@STACK_NAME-@@SERVICE_NAME.json | jq -r .Distribution.Id)   
aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id $DISTRIBUTION_ID \
       | jq .DistributionConfig.Enabled=false > cloudfront.json
ETAG=$(cat cloudfront.json | jq -r .ETag)  

cat cloudfront.json | jq -r .DistributionConfig > distribution.json

echo "Updating cloudfront to disabled"
ETAG=$(aws cloudfront update-distribution  --id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --if-match $ETAG  --distribution-config file://./distribution.json | jq -r .ETag)

rm distribution.json
rm cloudfront.json

echo "Waiting to be undeployed..."
OPERATION_STATUS="PENDING"
    while [ $OPERATION_STATUS = "PENDING" ]
    do
            OPERATION_STATUS=$(aws cloudfront get-distribution --id  $DISTRIBUTION_ID  | jq -r .Distribution.Status)
            if [ $OPERATION_STATUS != "Deployed" ]
            then
            echo "Status: $OPERATION_STATUS. Distribution not deployed yet. Sleeping additional 15s...."
                    sleep 15s
            fi
    done

echo "Deleting Cloudfront distribution..."
aws cloudfront delete-distribution  --id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --if-match $ETAG
```

Answer (score 0):

imperalix's answer works perfect for me! Let me add two more basic commands just incase some new comers (like me) need it:

1. To list all the distributions. From where you can find the id.

```
$ aws cloudfront list-distributions
```

2. To delete the distribution. But as it was mentioned, it takes some time after you disable the distribution.

```
$ aws cloudfront delete-distribution --id E123456 --if-match ETag123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution tied together as a bash script without creating any extra temporary files. My use case was for an S3 static site where I wanted to disable and delete the Cloudfront distribution for the static site

```
#!/bin/bash

wait=true
# validate supported platforms
for param in "$@"
do
    if [[ "$param" == "--no-wait" ]]
    then
        wait=false
    fi
done

s3_static_site=somebucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
existing_distro_json=$(aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[?Origins.Items[0].DomainName=='$s3_static_site'] | [0]")
if [ "$existing_distro_json" == "null" ]
then
  echo "Cloudfront distribution for $s3_static_site was already deleted"
else
  distro_id=$(echo $existing_distro_json | jq -r '.Id')

  # Need another call to get the details as its required for the etag and for the full update
  existing_distro_details_json=$(aws cloudfront get-distribution --id $distro_id)

  is_distro_enabled=$(echo $existing_distro_details_json | jq -r '.Distribution.DistributionConfig.Enabled')
  # Extract the ID and Etag used to select which record to delete
  distro_etag=$(echo $existing_distro_details_json | jq -r '.ETag')

  # Need to make a separate AWS CLI call because the etag does not appear in the list-distributions

  if [ $is_distro_enabled == true ]
  then
    # In the response I only want to select the "DistributionConfig" element raising it to the parent and then set 'Enabled' to false
    disabled_distro_json=$(echo $existing_distro_details_json | jq -r '.Distribution.DistributionConfig | .Enabled = false')

    echo "Disabling Cloudfront distribution $distro_id"
    aws cloudfront update-distribution --id $distro_id --if-match $distro_etag --distribution-config "$disabled_distro_json"

    if [ $wait == true ]
    then
      echo "Waiting for Cloudfront distribution $distro_id to be disabled, this can take up to 15 minutes..."
      aws cloudfront wait distribution-deployed --id $distro_id
      # The etag is updated after disabling, re-read to get the new value
      distro_etag=$(aws cloudfront get-distribution --id $distro_id | jq -r '.ETag')
    else
      echo "Not waiting for distribution to be disabled, delete id $distro_id manually at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home#distributions:"
    fi
  fi

  if [[ $is_distro_enabled == false || ($is_distro_enabled == true && $wait == true) ]]
  then
    echo "Cloudfront distribution disabled, deleting"
    aws cloudfront delete-distribution --id $distro_id --if-match $distro_etag
  fi
fi
```