# Cloudfront Distribution: Deployed but not enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to test a Cloudfront distribution that's been deployed but not enabled?

Would be nice to test things before flicking the switch!

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you want to test and what flicking the switch means?  You could do some tests with curl or hosts file tricks to simulate having CloudFront in your path.

Comment: Test: checking all the settings you've set in CloudFront are correct (e.g. SSL certificate, etc). Flicking the switch == Enabling the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against enabling/disabling a CloudFront distribution. When a CloudFront distribution is created, it is **fully functional**. Thus, you can fully test it once it is created.

There is **no cost** in having an 'enabled' CloudFront distribution -- charges only relate to data throughput.

If you are referring to **the ability to 'test' a change** to your CloudFront distribution, then you could **create a second distribution** to test the configuration before updating the 'live' distribution, or even a **test path** within the distribution.

Comment: Technically, there is an enable/disable feature.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206116/aws-cli-disable-distribution

Comment: Oops, thanks! You *can* enable/disable a distribution (it's even in the Management Console). I've updated my answer. However, there's not much use having a disabled distribution, since it cannot be used for testing.